# When installing Ubuntu on Hyper-V, disk becomes read-only

Tags: linux, hyper-v

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.5 Server (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2, in a Hyper-V Gen1-based VM. The installation will randomly hang, with `dmesg` eventually showing errors like:

```
sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
```

I have a very similar VM that's been working fine. The `dmesg` output on the two systems first diverges at about 126 seconds after boot-up (although this may be due to it being an installer boot, as opposed to a standard boot):

```
[  126.482972] NTFS driver 2.1.30 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
xor: measuring software checksum speed
   prefetch64-sse: 16009.000 MB/sec
   generic_sse: 15008.000 MB/sec
xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (16009.000 MB/sec)
raid6: sse2x1    9322 MB/s
raid6: sse2x2   11511 MB/s
raid6: sse2x4   13061 MB/s
raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (13061 M/s)
raid6: using intx recovery algorithm
bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
Btrfs loaded
JFS: nTxBlock = 7892, nTxLock = 63140
SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode, numbers, no debug enabled
EXT4-fs (sda1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
EXT4-fs (sda1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
EXT4-fs (sda1): write access unavailable, cannot proceed
EXT4-fs (sda1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
EXT4-fs (sda1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[  127.334559] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access unavailable, cannot proceed
```

And after some time,

```
[  182.830804] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[  230.779000] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0xa
               (repeated x times...)
[  241.151746] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x3 scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x8
               (also repeated x times)
[  251.155963] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x0 scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x8
[  251.155973] sd 2:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
               (repeated x times again)
[  251.155987] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[  251.155988] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda]
[  251.155989] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  251.155991] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[  251.155992] Write(10): 2a 00 04 c1 09 00 00 00 08 00
[  251.155996] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 79759616
[  251.155999] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 9969696
[  251.156000] lost page write due to I/O error on sda1
[  251.156011] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
```

Which eventually percolates up to the EXT4 driver.
With EXT3, similar error messages show up, but the driver never calls it quits, so the install just hangs.

---

Notes:

Something similar seems to happen on [Windows Azure-based (cloud) VMs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cae5d9d5-65a3-41b7-83d6-3cc24c418c18/vm-becomes-unresponsive-or-disk-becomes-readonly?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows). The linked page suggests that you stop and start the VM, which is implied to move it to a different host.

[This thread](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1304.3/02995.html) mentions that Hyper-V will stall I/O when the underlying disk returns an error, and that this stall causes weird behavior.

- The VHDX disk image is located on a Windows Storage Space device (Microsoft RAID-ish technology).

[This thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1157952) suggests that it is specific to using the `storvsc` driver with ext4 file systems, with SCSI `WRITE_SAME` commands being unsupported. This would have been checked in to Linux kernel 3.9-rc1, and definitely included in the Linux 3.13 kernel shipped with Ubuntu 12.04.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the host Hyper-V server had run out of disk space.

Since there are multiple levels of indirection between:

1. real physical disk
2. virtual disk (hosted by Windows Storage Spaces on physical disks)
3. disk image (dynamic .vhdx file hosted on the virtual disk)
4. Linux file system (hosted on the dynamic disk image)

it took some time for the various levels to actually fill up and pass the error down to the next level. What finally indicated the issue was another VM complaining that it was out of disk space (but only after having completed a ~4 GB Ubuntu install!).

I replaced one of the disks (500 GB => 4 TB), and added it to the storage pool, which got everything working again. I then rebuilt the disk pool with some [PowerShell commands](http://www.hodgkins.net.au/storage/replace-failed-disk-in-storage-spaces-pool-with-powershell/) (Windows Server UI wasn't working):

```
Get-PhysicalDisk
$missingDisk = Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Lost Communication' }
$missingDisk | Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired
Repair-VirtualDisk –FriendlyName <VolumeName>
```